# Looking for a Crusader Paladin prestige class

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, paladin, tome-of-battle

I want to know if there's a published prestige class where I can get martial maneuvers and stances as well as divine spells.

Answer (score 10):

Ruby knight vindicator on *Tome of Battle* page 122 can be entered by a 4th-level paladin/1st-level crusader and will do exactly what you are looking for. It is, in fact, the only class that will. At 7th level, it gets the fantastic divine impetus ability, which allows you to use turn undead uses to gain extra swift actions.

Please note the Battle Blessing feat from *Complete Champion*, which makes all paladin spells a swift action. This is excellent for all paladins, but for paladin-based ruby knight vindicators it becomes absolutely amazing.

In addition, either the Dynamic Priest feat from *Legends of the Twins* or the Serenity feat from *Dragon Compendium* is highly recommended for any paladin that cares about his spellcasting, as they reduce the multiple-ability-dependence of the class. Dynamic Priest allows you to ignore Wisdom as your bonus spells become Charisma-based, while Serenity allows you to ignore Charisma as all your paladin class features become Wisdom-based. That means you can focus more on one or the other and have more uses of turn undead and more spells.

Also note that ruby knight vindicator, as written, requires you to worship Wee Jas. Normally, paladins don’t actually have strict requirements about their faith—you could argue that praying to an evil god is an evil act and thus against their code, but there is no explicit rule about it and otherwise you’re definitely okay. The Forgotten Realms has stricter rules, but Wee Jas is from Greyhawk anyway, and even in FR, an LN deity can sponsor LG paladins (*Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* suggests Azuth or Kelemvor as stand-ins for Wee Jas; both are LN and explicitly have orders of paladins—Kelemvor’s even get a special name, the Doomguides). But if for you do not wish to worship Wee Jas, *Tome of Battle* also includes this note:

> #### Adaptation
>
> Although this prestige class is specific to a single crusader order—the Ruby Knights of Wee Jas—you could easily adapt it to crusaders devoted to almost any other deity.

Notably, the example “ruby knight” vindicator in the book actually worships St. Cuthbert.

Finally, there is an [existing answer with discussion of various options for a paladin-based ruby knight vindicator](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/69323/4563), which may be useful. It focuses somewhat on healing specifically, but many of the techniques there will apply however you want to use your spells.

Comment: Would quicken spell be good with this class as well?

Comment: @cZairKolmoslink Battle Blessing makes Quicken Spell irrelevant; it’s basically a free Quicken Spell on *all* your paladin spells. Which is good, because barring some other effects reducing the cost of Quicken Spell, it’s impossible for a paladin to use it (even 1st-level spells, when quickened, become 5th-level spells and the paladin cannot cast spells of that level).

Comment: Wondering do you know what "golden saint" is for Standing Dragon? Idk what if does

Comment: @cZairKolmoslink Yes, that would be one of TheDementedOne’s homebrew disciplines, [Golden Saint](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?76150-Golden-Saint-Exalted-Martial-Arts-Discipline).

Comment: Ok, so does standing Dragon change anything for the prestige class? I see the fire breath but idk what else changes. Sorry for asking so much. I'm back at googling this stuff

Comment: @cZairKolmoslink The columns of the table are the god (this is for worshipers of Bahamut instead of worshipers of Wee Jas), the alignment (instead of requiring LN, this requires LG), name (instead of “ruby knight vindicator,” your char sheet should say “standing claw vindicator”), a discipline (instead of the Shadow Hand discipline, you use Golden Hand; the other disciplines are the same), and a 5th-level class feature (instead of the armored stealth feature, you get a 1/day metallic-dragon breath weapon).

Comment: Wait what do you do with the 4ranks in hiding? Does that change?

Comment: @cZairKolmoslink You really should read the introduction there, it’s all laid out. “The hide skill is replaced in both the prerequisites and the class skill list with the key skill for the new signature school.” So for Golden Saint, that’s Diplomacy.